# Jquery not recognizing events that takes place on the HTML templates that is generated on fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I am using Handlerbars.js and it gives me a dynamic template that is generated on the fly. When I do some Jquery events like click etc .. Jquery is not able to catch those events. Please help me out.

I want to trigger a event when the button with id **hitUp** is clicked

**HandlerBar.js code**

```
{{#each this}}
                          <div id="accordion2" class="panel-group">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a href="#{{log}}"  data-parent="#accordion2"
                                                data-toggle="collapse" class="btn-block" > <img
                                                class="img-rounded" src="/assets/images/default-food.png" /> {{log}} 
                                            </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="{{log}}">
                                        <div class="panel-body food-details">
                                            <div class="bm pzero col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="input-group spinner">
                                                    <input id="spinid" type="text"
                                                        name="demo_vertical2" class="form-control      input-sm"
                                                         /> <span class="input-group-btn             vertical">
                                                        <button id="hitUp" 
                                                            class="btn btn-default bootstrap-touchspin-up"
                                                            type="button">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                        <button id="hitDown"
                                                            class="btn btn-default bootstrap-touchspin-down "
                                                            type="button">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
```

**HTML code**

```
    <div id="accordion2" class="panel-group">
     </div>
```

**Jquery code**

**Try1**

```
  $('body').on("click",'#hitUp',function(){
  console.log("Functionclicked")
  });
```

**Try2**

```
$('#hitUp').click(function(){
  console.log("Functionclicked")
  });
```

**Try3**

```
 $( document ).ready(function(    $('body').on("click",'#hitUp',function(){
  console.log("Functionclicked")
  });){})
```

I have tried the above Jquery methods but no use. Give me some solutions

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548265/handling-jquery-onclick-event-on-handlebars

Comment: it didnt help me already checked

Comment: I don't know,handlebars but isn't it creating a loop: `{{#each this}}`?

Comment: You know that the ID is `hitUp`, not `htiUp`, and that ID's are unique ?

Comment: sorry while typing Here i gave wrong id but in my machine its the same id

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah its generating loops

Comment: @karthe But IDs must be unique on document context, use class instead. Even if using duplicate IDs should work when using delegation

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah its generating loops

Comment: If #hitUp doesn't exist when the jQuery code runs, then it won't attach the event handler to anything. Try using .on() instead. Edit: nevermind, just realized your third attempt uses .on(), I missed it before.

Comment: @MikeWillis already I tried .on() I mention that in my first try code segment buddy

Comment: @MikeWillis errors are coming because of two functions buddy

Comment: As A.Wolff already said: If you are generating this piece of HTML twice or more in a loop, you cannot use ID's in any of those elements. ID's must be unique, using duplicate ID's will break your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in the link that @adeno posted, jQuery event handlers need to be registered as the very last thing that happens when all the JavaScript files and libraries are loaded. Calling $(document).ready() does not mean that all JS files have been loaded, it just means that the DOM has been put in place and is ready for manipulation. If you're going to do more DOM manipulation with a library like Handlebars, you need to make sure that your event handlers are registered after all that dynamic generation has already happened.

So if this is my template:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div>{{body}}</h1>
<br />
{{#each buttonIds}}
    <input type="button" id="{{this}}" value="Click me" />
{{/each}}
```

And this is my javascript:

```
var data = {
    title: 'The Title',
    body: 'Document Body',
    buttonIds: [ 'hitUp1', 'hitUp2', 'hitUp3' ]
};
var templateScript = $('#header').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);
$(document.body).append(template(data));

$('#hitUp1').on('click', function () { alert('clicked 1'); });
$('#hitUp2').on('click', function () { alert('clicked 2'); });
$('#hitUp3').on('click', function () { alert('clicked 3'); });
```

I'm waiting til very last to register the on click handlers, and they are each unique identifiers.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/1hxccgyz/1/) is a working fiddle to demonstrate what I'm saying.

Comment: Shouldn't using .on() attached to the body, or even the document, get around the problem of dynamic content generated after doc ready has run? For example $(document).on("click",".hitUp",function(){});

Comment: Yeah that would work too, just make sure you're using the '#' in front of the ID name. @karthe Technically, the code from "Try #3" should be working, but there looks to be some syntax problems. It should read `$( document ).ready(function() { $('body').on('click', '#hitUp', function() {
  console.log("Functionclicked");
  }); );` which is really confusing to read with all the nested functions.

Answer (score -2):

was facing the same issue. use

```
$('body').on("change", '#amountType', function (){

});
```

this worked for me