# How do I add event listeners to Handlebars templates after compilation?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, templating

I have a simple template setup that looks like this:

```
<script id="entry" type="text/x-handlebars-template">                                                                                                                                                           

  <p>Some content</p>                                                                                                                                                                                           
  <h2>Language Select:</h2>                                                                                                                                                                                     

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">English</button>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

  <h2>Ready:</h2>                                                                                                                                                                                               
  <button type="button" id="play" class="btn btn-success">Play</button>                                                                                                                                         
  <button type="button" id="stop" class="btn btn-danger">Stop</button>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

</script>
```

However, also in my document I have a script with the following content:

```
var playButton = document.querySelector('#play');

playButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {                                                                                                                                                               
  sendMessage('Cue', 'Play');                                                                                                                                                                                     
}, false);
```

Most of the time, (but not always) because of the async nature of javascript, this returns:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

If I wrap that code in a `setTimeout` of some amount, it will always work.

Can someone please explain to me the best way to add event listeners from scripts to generated template content?

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548265/handling-jquery-onclick-event-on-handlebars) but it seems like the way they suggest is just to add a delay before adding the event listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, forget my previous answer.

You need render template for first, then insert this html to body...

```
var source = document.querySelector("#some-template").innerHTML; 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
document.body.innerHTML = template();
```

and then add listeners...

http://jsfiddle.net/jwrae0n2/

Comment: A simple change to the code breaks it - with the error "play" is not defined.

In the HTML
<button type="button" id="play" class="btn btn-success" onclick="play">Play</button>

Inside JavaScript
function play() {
  alert('play'); 
}